# How to overwrite the input integer with an integer

Tags: pine-script

How do I have to set the integer `bgTrans`, so that it would not result in the following error? I do understand, that it needs to be of the type `input.integer`. But what if I want to change that value programmaticly? Then I need to change the value of the `input.integer`. How can I do so?

```
line 30: Cannot call 'bgcolor' with 'transp'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: input integer
```

here the code

```
backgroundColour = allowedToTrade ? color.green : color.red
int bgTrans = allowedToTrade ? 50 : 95
plotchar(bgTrans, "transparency", "", location = location.top)    
bgcolor(color=backgroundColour, transp= bgTrans)
```

Answer (score 0):

`transp` will be marked as deprecated soon. What does work, is to use `color.new` instead. See below. Here it also accepts simple integers as variables.

```
backgroundColour = allowedToTrade ? color.green : color.red   
bg_t_allowed := allowedToTrade ? 50 : 95
bgcolor(color.new(backgroundColour, transp = bg_t_allowed))
```